# How to force pip install a package compiling it (no binary) but using a previous specific version

Tags: pip

I am trying something like this:

```bash
pip install -U --no-cache-dir --force-reinstall --ignore-installed --no-binary :all: pysam==0.15.4
Collecting pysam==0.15.4
  Downloading pysam-0.15.4.tar.gz (1.6 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 1.6 MB 455 kB/s
Skipping wheel build for pysam, due to binaries being disabled for it.
Installing collected packages: pysam
    Running setup.py install for pysam ... done
Successfully installed pysam-0.16.0.1
```

after a while, where things are being compiled, I got version 0.16.0.1 (the latest) and I don't want that!

Comment: Try making a virtual environment and activate it. Then install your package.